# Member variables cannot be correctly converted to lambda expressions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

As above

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) : Comparable<Person> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Person): Int {
        return compareValuesBy(this, other, Person::name, Person::age)
    }
}
```

The above code is running correctly, when I convert to the following code, I can't get the correct result.

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) : Comparable<Person> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Person): Int {
        return compareValuesBy(this, other, { name }, { age })
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? Why do you think that syntax would work

Comment: What do you mean "Get a wrong result"?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I  think what member variables can do, lambda can do it, so I want to convert it.

Comment: @Cililing 
`val person = listOf(Person("Bob", 20), Person("Bob", 12)`
 `println(person[0] > person[1])`

Comment: In the book 《Kotlin in action》page 187

Comment: You need to use `it.name`, not `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **it** inside curly brackets and then access name and age. if you don't do that compiler accept your first argument( after **this**, **other**) that is **name** in this case as **Person** Object not String

This code will work for you:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) : Comparable<Person> {
  override fun compareTo(other: Person): Int {
    return compareValuesBy(this,other,{it.name},{it.age})
   }
}
```